# Add dynamic number of parameters to http sampler

Tags: jmeter

I am looking for a way to add dynamic parameters[name:value] to http sampler.

i have found it for headers but not for parameters .

i have json file which contains method,parameters, headers,body, authorization according to the values i need to construct and send the http request.

I succeeded till setting HOST,PORT,PATH,HEADERS..

I want to set it for body,authorization,parameters before sending the http request.

The below is the groovy code in which i have parsed the json content to jsonparser from json parser i am setting the above http .

```
 String fileContents = new File('../../src/resources/testInput.txt').text
def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
def inputjson = slurper.parseText fileContents
    String httpmethod = inputjson.Method
    sampler.setMethod(httpmethod);

 inputjson.Headers.each{log.info it.each{
key,value -> log.info key 
log.info value
 sampler.getHeaderManager().add(new Header(key,value ));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea , I have found partial answer for  query parameters.

```
 inputjson.QueryParams.each{ it.each{
    key,value -> 
     sampler.addArgument(key,value);
    }
```